# What does net.ipv4.tcp_app_win do?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, tcp-ip, algorithms

I can't figure out why the `tcp_adv_win_scale`
and `tcp_app_win` variables coexist in Linux. 
The information from [tcp(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) says:

For `tcp_adv_win_scale`:

> *`tcp_adv_win_scale`* (integer; default: 2; since Linux 2.4)
>
> Count buffering overhead as *`bytes/2^tcp_adv_win_scale`*,  if
> *`tcp_adv_win_scale`* is greater than 0; or
> *`bytes-bytes/2^(-tcp_adv_win_scale)`*,
> if *`tcp_adv_win_scale`* is less than
> or equal to zero.
>
> The socket receive buffer space is shared between the
> application and  kernel. 
> TCP maintains part of the buffer as the TCP
> window, this is the size of the receive window advertised to the
> other end.  The rest of the space is used as the "application"
> buffer, used to isolate the network from scheduling and
> application latencies. 
> The *`tcp_adv_win_scale`* default value of 2
> implies that the space used for the application  buffer  is  one
> fourth that of the total.

And for `tcp_app_win`:

> *`tcp_app_win`* (integer; default: 31; since Linux 2.4)
>
>   This  variable  defines  how  many  bytes  of the TCP window are
>   reserved for buffering overhead.
>
> A maximum of (*`window/2^tcp_app_win`*, mss) bytes in the window are
> reserved  for the application buffer.  A value of 0 implies that
> no amount is reserved.

So I'm not sure of understanding what does `tcp_app_win` exactly change. 
It seems to me that both variables can be used to tweak the TCP application buffer, therefore there is no need of changing them together. I am correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this information that talks about `tcp_adv_win_scale`. The page is titled: [TCP performance tuning - how to tune linux](http://www.acc.umu.se/~maswan/linux-netperf.txt).

*excerpt*

> TCP performance is limited by latency and window size (and overhead, which
>   reduces the effective window size) by window_size/RTT (this is how much data
>   that can be "in transit" over the link at any given moment).
>
> To get the actual transfer speeds possible you have to divide the resulting
>   window by the latency (in seconds):
>
> The overhead is: window/2^tcp_adv_win_scale (tcp_adv_win_scale default is 2)
>
> So for linux default parameters for the recieve window (tcp_rmem):
>   87380 - (87380 / 2^2) = 65536.
>
> Given a transatlantic link (150 ms RTT), the maximum performance ends up at:
>   65536/0.150 = 436906 bytes/s or about 400 kbyte/s, which is really slow today.
>
> With the increased default size:
>   (873800 - 873800/2^2)/0.150 = 4369000 bytes/s, or about 4Mbytes/s, which
>   is resonable for a modern network. And note that this is the default, if
>   the sender is configured with a larger window size it will happily scale
>   up to 10 times this (8738000*0.75/0.150 = ~40Mbytes/s), pretty good for
>   a modern network.
>
> 2.6.17 and later have resonably good defaults values, and actually tune
>   the window size up to the max allowed, if the other side supports it. So
>   since then most of this guide is not needed. For good long-haul throughput
>   the maxiumum value might need to be increased though.

I was able to follow that but didn't quite understand the relationship, if any, between these 2 variables.

I only marginally understood what that was trying to explain. At the core it sounds like this parameter to scale the amount of buffering space is to be used for TCP and for the application.

Searching a bit more I found these explanations which made more sense. The page was titled: [Ipsysctl tutorial 1.0.4 - Chapter 3. IPv4 variable reference](http://www.frozentux.net/ipsysctl-tutorial/chunkyhtml/tcpvariables.html).

*excerpt*

> 3.3.2. tcp_adv_win_scale
>
> This variable is used to tell the kernel how much of the socket buffer space should be used for TCP window size, and how much to save for an application buffer. If tcp_adv_win_scale is negative, the following equation is used to calculate the buffer overhead for window scaling:
>
> Where bytes are the amount of bytes in the window. If the tcp_adv_win_scale value is positive, the following equation is used to calculate the buffer overhead:
>
> The tcp_adv_win_scale variable takes an integer value and is per default set to 2. This in turn means that the application buffer is 1/4th of the total buffer space specified in the tcp_rmem variable.
>
> 3.3.3. tcp_app_win
>
> This variable tells the kernel how many bytes to reserve for a specific TCP window in the TCP sockets memory buffer where the specific TCP window is transfered in. This value is used in a calculation that specifies how much of the buffer space to reserve that looks as the following:
>
> [image: ss of formula]
>
> As you may understand from the above calculation, the larger this value gets, the smaller will the buffer space be for the specific window. The only exception to this calculation is 0, which tells the kernel to reserve no space for this specific connection. The default value for this variable is 31 and should in general be a good value. Do not change this value unless you know what you are doing.

Based on these explanations it sounds like the first parameter, `tcp_adv_win_scale` is controlling the split of the socket buffer space in terms of how it get's carved up for TCP window use vs. application buffer.

Whereas the 2nd parameter, `tcp_app_win` is specifying the number of bytes to reserve for the application buffer mentioned in the `tcp_adv_win_scale` description.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my findings from kernel sources:

- tcp_adv_win_scale is used in macro [tcp_win_from_space in include/net/tcp.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16/source/include/net/tcp.h#L1404). This macro is used in [function tcp_grow_window in net/ipv4/tcp_input.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L495).
  Seems that it is used only for established connections, not on connect.
  Default value for this parameter is 1, which result in 50% of rcv buffer for application.
- tcp_app_win is used in [function tcp_init_buffer_space in net/ipv4/tcp_input.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L535).
  Seems that it is used only on connect and not for established connections.
  Default value for this parameter is 31, which result in 0.0% of rcv buffer for application.

I would say that logic is not to reserve buffer for application in a new connections and grow it upon receiving data.
That way initial rwnd theoretically could be advertised as big as the whole buffer is. Sender will send that much of data. Receiver buffer will fill up, receiver will shrink win and increase application portion of buffer according to tcp_adv_win_scale.
So, as mentioned in [@slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94830) answer - there seems to be no reason for touching tcp_app_win.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave a link to the source code you are talking about. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.